# How does STL containers keep track of the current size of container over the total size?

Tags: c++, stl

Given

```
vector<int> a;
```

If `a.push_back()` is done, how does the `vector` knows whether to increase the size by reallocating memory or there is space available (Because `vector` allocates some extra space when size is full to reduce overhead).

P.S. Does same technique applies for other types of containers like `stack`, `queue` etc.

I think that it does the same thing as **"struct" in C.**

Comment: Implementation specific, but a common solution has `vector` made of three three pointers: beginning of buffer, end of buffer, and where in the buffer the next item goes. If the last two are the same, the `vector` is full and needs to be resized. Size is computed by subtracting the beginning pointer from the next pointer.

Comment: `stack` and `queue` may be built atop a `vector`, but the default for `queue` is to use a `deque`. [deque is built very differently from a `vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), so the full logic will be different.

Comment: Suggest you examine the internals of `vector` on your own compiler using the debugger to see the state information needed. Since these containers are templates the source is right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `capacity()` returns the number of items that can be stored in the vector without a reallocation.

The method `size()` returns the number of items which are currently stored in the vector.

Prior to inserting another item, it stands to reason that if `size() == capacity()` then more capacity will need to be made available. This will involve a reallocation to make more capacity available.

> Does same technique applies for other types of containers like stack, queue etc.

stack and queue are built on top of other std containers. These underlying containers (normally vector or deque) employ a similar technique.

> I think that it does the same thing as "struct" in C.

No.

Comment: So after each operation on container, all the methods are updated and thus vector is slower than arraylist ?

Answer (score -1):

In general, a vector ( and incidently a List in C# ), will allocate a block of memory.  As you add elements to it, it will mark more and more of that memory as consumed.  Then, when the block is full, it will allocate a new larger block, copy the contents into the new larger block, and delete the old one. Again the new larger block has more free space, and then, again, it can be filled up.  The idea is that vector always has a contiguous space so it can be used in applications where one would consider an array.  Because it has contiguous space, machine instructions for accessing a single element are trivial and so random access is very fast.  List in C# has similar semantics.  The implementation dependent thing has a lot to do with how much bigger that new bigger block is.  Sometimes they make it a percentage bigger. Sometimes they just double the size.

Comment: My question is different from what you have answered